# how to work with a CapRover project that is already in production

Tags: deployment, server, devops, caprover

How did I connect to an existing CapRover application? I have to upload the project that I have finished but to upload it to production they are using CapRover, there is already an old version of the project in production but I do not understand how to connect with it to be able to upload the new version until now I have only seen that the tutorials cover how to upload a new project from 0 but not how to work on one that already exists

i try with caprover login but i cannot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Caprover is a PAAS,you need to login into the admin url, usually `captain.yyy.uuu` and navigate to the app or simply ssh into the server hosting it and check for the particular container with your app.